# How do I make a cohort life expectancy data table in R?

Tags: r

Say if I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021), Age = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2), px = c(0.99,0.88,0.77,0.99,0.88,0.77,0.99,0.88,0.77))
```

Which should look like this

```
> df
  Year Age   px
1 2019   0 0.99
2 2019   1 0.88
3 2019   2 0.77
4 2020   0 0.99
5 2020   1 0.88
6 2020   2 0.77
7 2021   0 0.99
8 2021   1 0.88
9 2021   2 0.77
```

How do I make a cohort life expectancy table so that it looks like this:

```
  Year Age   px
1 2019   0 0.99
2 2020   1 0.88
3 2021   2 0.77
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using package `dplyr`

```r
df %>%
  filter(as.numeric(as.character(Year)) - as.numeric(as.character(Age)) == 2019)
#  A tibble: 3 x 4
#      id  Year   Age    px
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  2019     0  0.99
# 2     5  2020     1  0.88
# 3     9  2021     2  0.77
```

Included @Ian Campbell's improvement.

Comment: Why do I get this error? (Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Year, Age) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors)

Comment: It worked, thanks! I do still get an error (Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion) which I think is caused by having one of the age as 110+ since in life tables they don't calculate past age 110. Although it doesn't really matter, but how can I remove it?

Comment: I suspect you are correct @WeiShung. To get rid of the rows that have NA, you can just add `%>%` to the end of line two and add a new line three `filter(!is.na(Age))`.

Comment: I got the message again, but this time my data only runs up until the year 2020, and the highest age is only 80. (I started at 1940) So it's unlikely to be caused by the 110+ data. None of my values shows NA, is it ok if I just ignore the warning? Does my data altered when this warning comes out?

Comment: Perhaps you should do some data cleaning first: `df$Age <- gsub("\\+", "", df$Age)` to remove `+`.

Comment: @WeiShung that is highly dependend on your data and what you are trying to do.